# how register LoggingProvider in IHostBuilder.ConfigureLogging with a specified parameter?

Tags: c#

I created a custom loggingprovider with the following constructor:

```cs
public FileWriterLoggerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, 
IOptions<LoggerFilterOptions> optionsLoggerFilterOptions, string logFilePath)
```

I created the following extension to register the logging provider.

```cs
        public static ILoggingBuilder AddFileWriterLogger(this ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder,  string path)
        {
            var serviceDescriptorFileProvider = ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, FileWriterLoggerProvider>();
            loggingBuilder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(serviceDescriptorFileProvider);
            return loggingBuilder;
        }
```

The problem with `ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggingProvider,FileWriterLoggerProvider>()` is I can't specify a value for the `logFilePath` parameter. The parameter `IServiceProvider serviceProvider,  IOptions<LoggerFilterOptions> optionsLoggerFilterOptions` should be resolved "normally" or with its defaults values.

The extension will be used like this:

```
}).ConfigureLogging((hostbuilderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                loggingBuilder.AddFileWriterLogger(loggingPath);
```

As I use `AddFileWriterLogger` in `ConfigureLogging` I don't have `IServiceProvider` available, and I can't use something like  `services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(x => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<FileWriterLoggerProvider>(provider.GetService<IServiceProvider >(),provider.GetService<IOptions<LoggerFilterOptions>>(), "myloggingpath"));`

Any idea how I can register the type `FileWriterLoggerProvider` and provide an own value for the `loggingpath` parameter?

Comment: What's the version of net core? Could you use ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in startup? Are you using a mvc project or is an windows service?

Comment: its a xamarin forms project using ihostbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using overload accepting implementation factory:

```cs
var serviceDescriptorFileProvider = ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider>(provider => new FileWriterLoggerProvider(
    provider, 
    provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<LoggerFilterOptions>>(),
    path));
```